# Merge with Rasterio in Python 3.7

Tags: python, rasterio

I am attempting to run this code:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed May 13 12:43:07 2020

@author: Matthew Farnham
"""
import gdal
import os.path
import rasterio
from rasterio.merge import merge
from rasterio.plot import show
import glob
import os
import numpy as np


with rasterio.Env(GDAL_TIFF_INTERNAL_MASK=True):
    PIXELTYPE = 'DEFAULT',
    TFW='YES'


    directory = r"H:\Projects\Countries\USA\State\Washington_DC\DTM\LIDAR\Datagateway\Unzipped\elevation"

    Output = r"E:\Previsico\PERM\Matthew\Previsico\7_Model_Workings\DEM_Mosaic\Data_Testing_Keep_empty\Trial1\Test3.tif"

    search_criteria = "*.tif"

    q = os.path.join(directory, search_criteria)

    print(q)

    dem_fps = glob.glob(q)

    print(dem_fps)


    Mosaic_files = []

    for i in dem_fps:
        src = rasterio.open(i)
        Mosaic_files.append(src)


    out_meta = src.meta.copy()




    mosaic, out_trans = merge(Mosaic_files)



    out_meta = src.meta.copy()



    out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                  "height": mosaic.shape[1],
                  "width": mosaic.shape[2],
                  "transform": out_trans,
                  "crs":"+proj= unknown",
                  "BigTIFF" : "yes",
                  }
                 )

    with rasterio.open(Output, "w", BigTIFF = 'YES', **out_meta) as dest:
        dest.write(mosaic)
```

I am running it in Python 3.7 in a 64-bit environment. The error is:"MemoryError: Unable to allocate 17.4 GiB for an array with shape (1, 70544, 66261) and data type float32"

I am trying to mosaic (merge) raster files (.tif) to create a raster dataset comprising all of the individual raster files. Is there a way to get Python to write it first as opposed to storing everything to memory?

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Do you have 17 GiB (1 GiB = 1073741824 bytes) of physical memory? If not, then you need to use this data in some other way (like writing to a file for example)

Comment: I have 16GB of RAM. So this should not be a problem... But how could I write to a file in python and keep adding the data to it?

Comment: 17 GiB > 16 GB. So you don't have enough memory to store that.

Comment: Yes you are correct. My Mistake. Is there a way to write files continually?